# How to remove Deleted items folder from Outlook PST file

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, pst

[image]

Hi,
I have created one PST file using C# code. My Sample code is here.

```
string pstlocation = @"C:\Users\{USER}\Desktop\PST Files\Test.pst";
Outlook._Application OutlookObject = this.Application;
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = null;
Outlook.Folder objRootFolder = null;
outlookNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");    

outlookNs.AddStore(pstlocation);
objRootFolder = outlookNs.Folders.GetLast() as Folder;
```

My PST file is Added successfully in outlook 2013. When i am try to delete **Deleted Items** but it is not deleted and it give us an error.

```
foreach (Folder objFolder in objRootFolder.Folders)
    {
            objFolder.Delete();
           //It gives an error.
    }
```

Error : An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in OutlookAddInPSTTest.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot delete this folder. Right-click the folder, and then click Properties to check your permissions for the folder. See the folder owner or your administrator to change your permissions.

===================================================================

So, how can i delete **Deleted Items** from PST file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you cannot delete the *Special* folders used by Outlook. There are a couple of MS Exchange utilities/clients that will allow it, however; Outlook will recreate them upon startup.

Reference: [Microsoft Support- Cannot delete default Outlook folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306253/cannot-delete-default-outlook-folders)

- Inbox
- Drafts
- Sent Items
- Deleted Items

Comment: After doing lost of research,
I am able to know that using PropertyAccessor, we are able to hide this folder but not able to delete this default folders.

Comment: To hide this folder, we have to set this http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B property true.